# How to use center widget for the child of a wrap widget without expanding the child to the full width?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When I use center in a text used in Wrap widget as shown in the code below:

```
Wrap(
   children: [
     Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
         vertical: 6.0),
       child: Container(
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: Colors.transparent,
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27),
           border: Border.all(
             color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.60)),
         ),
         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9,6,9,6),
         child: Center(<--placing this center widget makes the child expand to full width
           child: Text(
             'NTU',
             style: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.87),
               fontSize: 16.5,
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     )
   ]),
```

the container expands to the full width as shown below:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

But placing a center widget in the child of the Wrap widget seems to make it expand to the full width. Any suggestion on how to make it shrink to the child's width even when the center widget is used? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of creating custom widget. Try widget called `Chip()` give shape/border/etc to your choice. Try it if it works for your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `widthFactor` of `Center` widget to set its width to the child's width multiplied by this factor.

```
return Wrap(
   children: [
     Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
         vertical: 6.0),
       child: Container(
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: Colors.transparent,
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27),
           border: Border.all(
             color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.60)),
         ),
         padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9,6,9,6),
         child: Center(
           widthFactor: 1.5,
           child: Text(
             'NTU',
             style: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.87),
               fontSize: 16.5,
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     )
   ]),
```

Comment: Hey @Shubhamhackz, I tried adding the width factor and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving width to your container,

```
                          Wrap(
                          children: [
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 100,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27),
                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.60)),
                                ),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 6, 9, 6),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'NTU',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.87),
                                      fontSize: 16.5,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
```

Comment: Hi @MuhammedYesilmen, it seems that you have given the container a fixed width. That's not what I'm looking for as I want my container to expand and contract according to its child. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Wrap(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Flexible(
                                  child: SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                width: 100,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27),
                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.60)),
                                ),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 6, 9, 6),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'NTU',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.87),
                                      fontSize: 16.5,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                        
                                Flexible(
                                  child: SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

Comment: hi @liamspiegel, I need to use wrap so that the children can wrap around when they exceed the width of the screen. Using Row doesn't work for my case. Thanks though.